# Phalcon assign view variable inconsistent

Tags: phalcon, volt

Having a problem getting consistent behavior assigning variables to the view. For example:

In controller:

```
$this->view->media = Media::findFirst(['groupId=0', 'order' => 'RAND()', 'limit' => 1]);
```

In view:

```
        {% if media is defined %}
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="{{ static_url('img/media/thumbs/' ~ media.name) }}" class="img-round">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>{{ media.title }}</h3>
                <p>{{ media.description }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
```

Which is parsed like:

```
        <?php if (isset($media)) { ?>
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->url->getStatic('img/media/thumbs/' . $this->media->name); ?>" class="img-round">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3><?php echo $this->media->title; ?></h3>
                <p><?php echo $this->media->description; ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
```

The problem is that when the parsed version of the template, $media is not accessible via $this so the isset($media) passes, but the references to $this->media returns nothing.

Any way to force $media to be local in scope?

Comment: Seen this once. Back then it was because I had in controller assigned `$this->data` and `$this->view->data`. I's your situation the same?

Comment: Nice suggestion but code above is actual copy/paste so its correct. Interestingly, it looks like everything is scoped to $this-> until it is used in a control (e.g. {% for item in medias %} ), then item is local.

My current workaround is to pass it as an array using $model->toArray()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it.

## Misbehaviour description

You have probably declared a `media` module in your `DI()`. I was trying quite a lot to reproduce that error, and got it finally when i set a dumb `media` service among configuration files:

```
$di->set('media', function() {
    return new \stdClass();
});
```

and than got the same behavior you have - Volt during compilation is not sure, what variable to use and choses `$this->media` (`DI::get('media')`) instead of `$media` or `$this->view->media` var for obtaining data.

## Solution

If you dont want to resign from calling you findFirst result under that variable name, you may bypass that by using View in volt directly:

```
{% if view.media is defined %}
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="{{ static_url('img/media/thumbs/' ~ view.media.name) }}" class="img-round">
        <div class="caption">
            <h3>{{ view.media.title }}</h3>
            <p>{{ view.media.description }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

it will generate `$this->view->media` calls instead of `$this->media` ones.

+1 on that question.